# Looking for a short story about visiting the Vietnam War Memorial

Tags: story-identification

I may have read this story in Omni or Aboriginal SF, and I'm almost certain I read this story in the 90s.

It was about a man visiting the (then newly open) Vietnam War Memorial in Washington DC, and remembering things about his time in the army during the war - both people he served with and some awful things he'd done.

He gets to the wall, and finds some names of people he knew, and then he keeps looking along the wall and the names start to flicker - he sees other names, names he'd forgotten, and even the name of a poor Vietnamese kid that he (the POV character) had killed.

It's not a horror story, really, but it is a melancholy story.

Comment: The flickering names - were they just in his head - like, a vision brought on by guilt, memory, etc - or is it something supernatural? What makes this sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: They weren't just in his head - he talked to someone else who was there looking at other things and he said that the wall moved for him too.